# Find basis for anhilators $(S+T)^{0}, (S \cap T)^{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

So the given subspaces are

$ S = \mathbf{span} \{  (1,0,1,-1)^{T}, (0,1,0,-1)^{T}  \}  $

and

$ T = \mathbf{span}\{(-1,1,3,1)^{T}\} $

Using identities

$ (S + T)^{0} = S^{0} \cap T^{0}$ and
$ (S \cap T)^{0} = S^{0} + T^{0}$

I can determine basis for $S^{0}$ and $T^{0}$ first.

So for S^{0} I find

$B_{1} = \{x_{1}-x_{3}, x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}\}$ to be a basis.

Now for $T^{0}$ is where I start having problems.

$T^{0}$ has dimension 3.

Since $ T = \mathbf{span}\{(-1,1,3,1)^{T}\} $

I rewrite its anhilator as

$T^{0} = \mathbf{span}\{\phi \in T^{*}: \phi(-1,1,3,1)^{T}=0\}$ (is this right?)

So I can just find three functionals in $T^{*}$ that vanish in $(-1,1,3,1)$

So a basis of $T^{0}$ is $ \{x_{1}+x_{3}, x_{2}-x_{4}, 3x_{2}-x_{3}\}$

Now to find a basis of $S^{0} + T^{0}$,
I take the span of the union of $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$.
Which I guess is correct, but this isnt an explicit answer, how can I fix this? I know I must eliminate one vector from the union, since the dimension of this sum of subspaces is at most 4.

Now for the basis of $ (S + T)^{0} = S^{0} \cap T^{0}$
Where I find the basis to be $\mathbf{span} \{ x_{1} \}$

Can I get some feedback on this? I really appreciate any help. Thanks.